# Is it possible to implement a C# print console app/service in an already existing javascript/html webapp?

Tags: javascript, printing-web-page

I have an app built in Javascript to be used in chrome's kiosk mode and I want to print a receipt in background without losing any focus of the main window (no print preview nor print dialog flashes).
After some research it seems to be impossible (due to browsers safety policies) if using only Javascript.

How can I bypass this?

edit 1: added js print function that receives an html document

```
function printTicket(printText) {
    w = window.open();
    w.document.write(printText);
    w.document.close();
    w.onload = setTimeout(function () {
        w.print();
        w.close();
    }, 250);
}
```

Comment: Add some code..

Comment: Create an ASP.Net site that serves up the pages to Chrome. The JS will then be able to send requests to the backend that will have the necessary capabilities.

Comment: or a backend using any server-side technology that you choose. ASP.NET is a reasonable choice but not, by far, the only one.